# Vba to enter cell "A1" in search box of a website and click on submit and get results

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to search a particular text in range "A1" and get the result in A2.
So far i have been able to open the URL, but not able to enter the value or select search button

I have tried somethings

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim IE As Object
Dim Value As String
Dim SearchBox As Object

Dim content As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set content = Range("A1")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "URL"

Do While IE.readyState <> 4 And IE.Busy                                          
    DoEvents
Loop

Set SearchBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("demoInput1")

'type text into the first (and probably the only) element

'with this HTML class name on this page

SearchBox(0).Value = content.Value
'now get a reference to the search button

Set SearchButton = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("demoButton button")

'click on the first (and presumably only) object in the collection

SearchButton(0).Click

End Sub
```

I am getting "object Variable or with block element not set" error.

Thanks in Advance

Error:

[image]

Comment: There is no declaration of SearchButton (Dim SearchButton) and also your string Value is a word You cannot use (assigned in vba)

Comment: I tried correcting as you said but still getting the same error

Comment: can you provide the url ideally, or at least the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit]  Does it make a difference if you step line by line through code with F8?

Comment: "https://www.twinword.com/api/text-similarity.php" There are 2 text input boxes in this URL. Please check .